# Does apply quota for Triggers total runtime to a user or a company?

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

[Google Apps Script Guides - Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) says that quota for "Triggers total runtime" is 6 hr / day for G Suite Business.
I'm not clear if it applies to each user or our company (G Suite contract).
I asked G Suite Support, but they didn't provided any answer to me since GAS is not G Suite core services.

Could anyone tell me if you know？
Thank you for your support in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Quota Limit is for per user per day. Suppose n number of scripts are running in a user account and all these n scripts takes x amount of running time in total than that should not exceed 360 minutes in total in a day.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer shabnam bharmal.  I feel at my ease now.